# Can I add arbitrary properties to DOM objects?

Tags: javascript, dom

Can I add arbitrary properties to JavaScript DOM objects, such as `<INPUT>` or `<SELECT>` elements?  Or, if I cannot do that, is there a way to associate my own objects with page elements via a reference property?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure, people have been doing it for ages. It's not recommended as it's messy and you may mess with existing properties.

If you are looping code with `for..in` your code may break because you will now be enumerating through these newly attached properties.

I suggest using something like jQuery's `.data` which keeps metadata attached to objects. If you don't want to use a library, re-implement `jQuery.data`

Comment: Cool... Is `data` used by jQuery itself or am I free to assign any value to it?

Comment: `$.data` is defined by jQuery. You would use it like `$('#el').data('key', 'value')`.

Comment: It's `$(element).data('name', value)` to set a value, and `$(element).data('name')` to read it.

Comment: I assume you know how to do it the manual DOM way, `el['data-foo'] = 'value';`

Comment: There are bugs/inconsistencies with `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` in IE, if you dont decide to use `$.data` prefix your attribute with `data-`

Comment: How would `for...in` loops break just by having an extra property?

Comment: One option these days (2023) would be to use a property keyed by a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) instead of a string - those are guaranteed not to clash with anything else and they are ignored by `for ... in`

Answer (score 48):

ECMAScript 6 has WeakMap which lets you associate your private data with a DOM element (or any other object) for as long as that object exists.

```
const wm = new WeakMap();
el = document.getElementById("myelement");
wm.set(el, "my value");
console.log(wm.get(el)); // "my value"
```

Unlike other answers, this method guarantees there will never be a clash with the name of any property or data.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that you have to maintain the `wm` reference throughout? Seems a little limiting.

Comment: You don't want to maintain that wm reference? No need to expose it, if you rather use a utility function like setArbitraryValueTo(el,value) or getArbitraryValueFrom(el).

Answer (score 32):

Yes, you can add your own properties to DOM objects, but remember to take care to avoid naming collisions and circular references.

```
document.getElementById("myElement").myProperty = "my value";
```

HTML5 introduced a valid way of attaching data to elements via the markup - using the `data-` attribute prefix.  You can use this method in HTML 4 documents with no issues too, but they will not validate:

```
<div id="myElement" data-myproperty="my value"></div>
```

Which you can access via JavaScript using `getAttribute()`:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").getAttribute("data-myproperty");
```

Comment: Should that last line be `setAttribute()`?

Comment: @alex: nope, still made a mistake though :-)

Comment: data- attributes can only store strings (or objects serializable/deserializable to/from strings), not general runtime objects, whereas setting a new property on a dom object can.

Comment: What's exactly the issue with circular references? An object A having a reference to an object B which has a reference to A is not an issue in general, so what is the situation that must be avoided in the case of arbitrary properties attached to a DOM element?

Comment: @matteo A circular reference *could* lead to a memory leak. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347203/circular-references-in-javascript-garbage-collector

Comment: @matteo - Back in 2010, when Andy wrote this answer, there was an issue in Internet Explorer related to DOM elements having references to JavaScript objects on arbitrary properties. But that was fixed in a later version of IE, so the circular references thing is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want to add properties to the object, or attributes to the element?

You can add attributes using `setAttribute`

```
var el = document.getElementById('myelement');
el.setAttribute('custom', 'value');
```

or you can just add properties to the javascript object:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myelement');
el.myProperty = 'myValue';
```

Comment: if anyone forgot the difference between property and attribute -> quick link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is wondering in 2015, yes, you can - **and** jQuery is doing just that in [data](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/9d76c0b163675505d1a901e5fe5249a2c55609bc/src/data/Data.js#L31). Just pick future-proof names like vendor prefixes or time-based random suffixes (jQuery).

Comment: But jQuery is using an internal cache were the data is saved, the data is not saved in the DOM Element itself. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200722/jquery-expando-properties

Comment: You linked to the master branch of jQuery. Since master branches change, please consider linking to a particular version.

Answer (score 2):

If you must, don't use standard HTML attributes. Here's a tutorial on using custom attributes:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

It's HTML5, but it's backward-compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I was exploring answers, none have mentioned that in modern JavaScript we can set attributes on `domElements` using `dataset` property, it could use on `HTMLOrForeignElement` *(that's a mixin of several features common to the `HTMLElement`, `SVGElement` and `MathMLElement` interfaces)*.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

> The `dataset` property on the HTMLOrForeignElement interface provides read/write access to all the custom data attributes `(data-*)` set on the element. This access is available both in HTML and within the DOM. It is a map of `DOMStrings`, one entry for each custom data attribute.

```js
let element = document.getElementById("test");
let footer = document.querySelector("#output");

/* get element values using camelCase names through .dataset */
let sample = element.dataset.sample;
let sampleNumber = element.dataset.sampleNumber;

let dataFromElement = sample + " :: " + sampleNumber;

footer.innerHTML = element.innerHTML  + dataFromElement;
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="test" data-sample="Sample" data-sample-number=34 />
<div id="output"> </div>
```

Although there are concerns about Internet Explorer support and performance on this you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#Issues).

Comment: The issue with this is that the dataset properties are just attributes and so passing in an object results in it being flattened to `[object Object]`.