# jQuery expando properties

Tags: jquery

I have a question on jQuery expando properties. Basically I would like to understand in VERY simple terms:

1. How this whole process works like how jQuery adds the expando property,
2. what is the criteria to add it to any element
3. What is the exact reason which makes jQuery lightweight
4. What exactly does the jQuery cache have?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Question 3 seems out of place but for the rest:

- `jQuery.expando` is a string which is basically `'jQuery' + uniqueid` (just a unique value)

Prior to version 1.4.4, the uniqueid is `current timestamp`.

After that from version 1.5.1, the uniqueid is `version+Math.random()` with dots replaced. To be clear, `"jQuery" + ( version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" )`.

- `jQuery.cache` is an object that will store the data values
- `Element[ jQuery.expando ]` is a int value/key that is where the object is stored in `jQuery.cache`
- `jQuery.cache[ Element[ jQuery.expando ] ]` is an object of that elements data props

## [Take a look at this to see what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/JrvNB/1/)

Comment: Why does jQuery set this expando property sometimes, e.g. on `Window`?