# With vanilla JavaScript, how can I access data stored by jQuery's .data() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

And before someone says:

```
document.querySelector('.myElem').getAttribute('data-*')
```

No, is not what I'm looking for. jQuery's `data()` has dual functions. 1) It queries an [HTML5 data attribute](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) which can be seen in the HTML code like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>
$( "div" ).data( "role" ) === "page";
$( "div" ).data( "lastValue" ) === 43;
$( "div" ).data( "hidden" ) === true;
$( "div" ).data( "options" ).name === "John";
```

and 2) the ones that are set by `.data(name, value)` which are hidden in a jQuery internal Object, to which the documentation only says "to save information under the names 'events' and 'handle'", yet I haven't figured out a way to access them or what actually creates them.

So, my question stands, how can I access the jQuery data values from plain JavaScript?

Just so it's absolutely clear... let me put more emphasis: **I don't want the `data-` HTML attributes, but the jQuery object data**.

Comment: That's actually an implementation detail. Data stored through jQuery's `data()` setter is not stored in the DOM, but in an internal cache associated with the element. You would have to duplicate quite a lot of jQuery's implementation to retrieve that data in plain JS, and that implementation can change in the future, so I don't think this would be a good idea.

Comment: You can't get at those properties without the jQuery object as that's where they're stored. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7201455/2685386) shows how to get it out of the internal representation, in case you're interested

Comment: @Braiam What's the point of trying to access something in another way than the prescribed `$(...).data` way? It's like saying, you would like to use some API's features, but without going through that API. Pointless?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You are right, that it's stored internally, however it's quite easy to access.

Comment: @dsfq, my point was less about easiness than reliability: the "current" way to access that data can change tomorrow. (But note the implementation of `internalData()` in the version of jQuery I'm currently using -- 1.11.0 -- is about a hundred lines long.)

Comment: I 100% agree that one should not access `data` other then via `$.data` API. But if OP wants to know where jQuery stores those values, the answer is simple: event handlers and data are stored in `$.cache`.

Comment: @dfsq that sounds like an answer if you are able to expand it. I'm about to take another approach for the problem (getting rid of the method that sets them in first place instead).

Comment: @Braiam You still didin't answer why using `$.data` is an issue? If you do not like how it behaves, then use your own implementation...?

Comment: @plalx why would you replace jQuey with plain JS? Normally is because jQuery can result expensive, right? I discovered that in my implementation all the `$.data()` calls are expensive enough that a reimplementation seems worth the effort, but after consulting the documentation I didn't find a way.

Comment: @Braiam `$.data` probably isn't the expensive part; it's probably the querying of the element from the DOM that's expensive. You can fix this by caching the selected element.

Comment: You can simply use `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("data-your attr-name");` and use `setAttribute` in similar way

Comment: @Maverick again... thats' not what I want!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery uses internal object called `$.cache` to store event handlers and data values. `$.cache` is a simple dictionary which can look something like this:

```
{ 1: { data: { role: "page"}, events: { click: ...} }, 2: { ... }}
```

The keys are all unique indexes corresponding to some DOM nodes. If your DOM element was previously touched by jQuery (attached events or to some data), you will see that it has a weird property similar to the one below:

```
jQuery17108624803440179676: 2
```

Here `jQuery17108624803440179676` is a unique string generated by jQuery when it was loaded on the page. This unique identifier is called "expando" and is stored as

```
$.expando
```

Now that you know how to access an individual element's internal data by bypassing jQuery's data API...

```
$.cache[element[$.expando]]
```

...you may ask why jQuery uses an intermediate object to store all DOM data and events. The reason is that it is a way to avoid memory leaks, which would be the case if `data` and events handlers were stored directly in DOM elements properties (due to circular references).

Having said all that, I want to emphasize that you should **not** work with node data objects other than that via the jQuery Data API for the simple reason that it handles all the complex stuff behind the scenes.

Comment: weird, `$.cache` is undefined, but `$("#id").data()` shows there's data associated with the object.

Comment: `$("#id").data()` also gives you data stored in *data attributes*, in this case `$.cache` may still be clean, if there are no events associated with this node or data assigned with `$('#id').data('some', 'thing')`.

Comment: No, I'm sure there are no data attributes associated with the object (I just created it, and there isn't `data-` in the HTML)

Comment: So what does `$("#id").data()` then produce?

Comment: `$('#id').data('some', 'thing')`
`[
<p id=​"id">​</p>​
]`
`$('#id').data()`
`Object {some: "thing"}`

Comment: Of course. But my question is how this is possible `$.cache is undefined, but $("#id").data() shows there's data associated with the object.`. Are you sure `$("#id").data()` gives you some object and still `$.cache` is not populated?

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, that's exactly what's happening. I changed the scope in the console one by one, yet `$.cache` returns `undefined`. I'm using Chromium 35.0.1916.153 Debian jessie/sid (274914) with jQuery 1.7 and 2.1.1 and the result is the same. `$.expando` works as expected, through.

Comment: @Braiam Note that `$.data` and `$(...).data` might not have the same implementation. I haven't digged the code yet, but I've seen performance tests that suggests they behave differently.

Comment: @dfsq can you add a link to the documentation of where the data values are stored so I can accept the answer?

Comment: @Braiam I haven't seen any official documentation on this internal stuff. Here is however [cool article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks#jquery-anti-leak-measures-and-leaks) on memory leaks in general, which also touches jQuery data `API`.

Answer (score 6):

From the comments, your motivation to bypass `$(...).data` seems to be based on the fact that it's causing performance issues.

I totally agree with @meagar on that point, `$(...).data` shouldn't be expensive enough to cause bottlenecks. However, if you continously re-query and re-wrap DOM elements as jQuery elements (e.g. `$('#someEl').data(...)` multiple times rather than caching `$('#someEl')` and do `$someEl.data(...)`, then it might be an issue.

Please also note that if you find yourself attaching a lot of data to DOM elements, you probably got your design wrong. Your data shouldn't live in the presentation layer and you shouldn't have to query the DOM or get a reference to a DOM element to access your data. Obviously, you might in some situations, but these shouldn't be the norm.

If you still want to build your own `data` feature, then here's an example. It's not optimized, but you should get the idea:

*Note that WeakMap is only available in modern browsers, but without it we would be leaking memory, unless you provide a mechanism to destroy the cached attributes expendo object when the associated DOM element gets destroyed.*

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6v4379r9/)

[**JSPERF**](http://jsperf.com/data-vs-jqdata) *(the test might not be fair, since I'm not sure my implementation does everyting `$(...).data` does)*

```
var data = (function () {
    var attributes = new WeakMap();

    return function (el, attr, val) {
        var elAttrs = attributes.get(el),
            isSetOperation = arguments.length > 2;

        if (isSetOperation) {
            if (!elAttrs) attributes.set(el, elAttrs = {});
            elAttrs[attr] = val;
        } else {
            return datasetOrCachedAttrsValue();
        }

        function datasetOrCachedAttrsValue() {
            var attrVal = el.dataset[attr];

            return typeof attrVal !== 'undefined'?
                attrVal: 
                elAttrs && elAttrs[attr];
        }
    };
})();

var div = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(data(div, 'test')); //test
console.log(data(div, 'notexisting')); //undefined
data(div, 'exists', true);
console.log(data(div, 'exists')); //true
```

> *"would be leaking memory, unless you provide a mechanism to destroy the
>   cached" - plalx*. Well even with WeakMap it still leaks for the same reason why
>   jQuery can cause leaks. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/6v4379r9/1/). –  dfsq

That was a good concern from @dfsq, but **[here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6v4379r9/2/)** that actually shows how WeakMap allows garbage collection once they key is unreachable, as opposed to jQuery's implementation that will hold on data (unless `$().remove` is used I believe).

Use the profiler and record heap allocations over time and compare the results. Here's what I got from 6 clicks on each button (one type of button per snapshot). We can clearly see that `$().data` is leaking while the custom `data` implementation using a `WeakMap` is not.

1. try to leak with `$().data`.

   [image]
2. try to leak with data

   [image]

Comment: `would be leaking memory, unless you provide a mechanism to destroy the cached`. Well even with `WeakMap` it still leaks for the same reason why jQuery can cause leaks. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/6v4379r9/1/).

Comment: @dfsq It's not because you remove an element from the DOM that it becomes unreachable. Your example doesn't prove there's a memory leak and in fact, as soon as the code will finish it's execution, the associated entry in the weak map will be destroyed, since `div` will not be reachable anymore. You can think of it this way: if you cannot retrieve the key to query the WeakMap, then the entry will be garbage collected. jQuery cannnot use WeakMap, since it must run in old browsers too and weak references cannot be shimmed.

Comment: `as the code will finish it's execution` what do you mean here by `finish execution`? To me it looks like `data(div, 'one')` will always be there even though `div` is not on the page anymore.

Comment: @dfsq Well, I mean once the `onload` will finish it's execution (because the code is running onload), `div` will now be unreachable since it's not part of the DOM and the `div` variable was local to the `onload` function. At that point, the associated object to that div element in the WeakMap will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I see what you mean, and look like it's true.

Comment: @dfsq I added a heap compare between `$().data` and `data`. You'll see that jQuery's implementation leaks memory where the custom one doesn't.

Comment: I know that jQuery leaks in this case. But it's interesting to see this comparison with WeakMap. In general great answer!

Comment: Do you have any other solutions on this? The above code is not right for me at line var attrVal = el.dataset[attr];

Comment: @thednp What do you mean by "not right"? Are you running the code in a modern browser that supports the `dataset`?

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment, I discovered there were issues on the way.