# How are JQuery widgets bound to DOM elements?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a question about how jquery widgets are bound to elements using the following syntax:

```
$( "#myElement" ).datepicker();
```

I have created my own datetime picker but it is bound to the INPUT using the following syntax:

```
new DatePicker( $("#myElement") );
```

In my case, I used an ES6 class.  the INPUT field is passed via the constructor and everything is handled from within the constructor automatically.  It works just like the jquery ui widget does.

Coming from a C++ background, I don't understand how the jquery widget is associated with the dom element.  Can someone please tell me how that works?  What is datepicker() returning and how is that bound to the dom element?

*I read some of the jquery widget factory documentation but decided against that since I did not want to include another dependency.  I found no information on how datepicker() is bound to the element.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you start here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ "*...`jQuery()` — which can also be written as `$()` — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements...*"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I looked into it as well as the jquery widget factory.  Although I'm using jquery which I think is wonderful for productivity as well as for writing clean and concise code, I will not be using the widget factory and will continue to create future widgets using the second instantiation form in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery-UI widget-DOM binding

jQuery-UI widgets are bound to their DOM element using the `jQuery.data()` API where the key is the full name of the widget [1].

You can see it in jQuery-UI widget factory source code:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1be45388176080418aef84f3c98fda2c10fcdc42/ui/widget.js#LL226C1-L226C1

```
    var instance = $.data( this, fullName );
```

Here, the low-level https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#jQuery-data-element-key call is used to retrieve the *instance* object of the widget bound to the DOM element `this` (the *instance* object stores the widget's state and methods).

That is, the widget instance object is stored in a jQuery-internal cache where it is associated to a DOM element and can be retrieved using [2]

```
   datepickerInstance = $("#myElement").datepicker("instance");
```

For example, in an event handler where `this` is a DOM element you would retrieve the instance object as follows `var datepickerInstance = $(this).datepicker("instance");`

## jQuery.data()

It is worth noting that the jQuery' .data() API https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key-value is NOT using HTML data attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes but is a jQuery-internal key-value store, where each DOM element has a separate store.

The following Stackoverflow answer has some implementation details about JQ's internal KV store: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201455/17839690

### How to inspect jQuery.data() in a browser

If you are in a browser devtools (F12) environment, it's possible - but a bit cumbersome - to retrieve jQuery data values:
First, select the DOM element, then in the browser console type `$($0).data()`. This should print all jQuery.data key-value pairs of the currently selected element `$0` in the console.

---

[1] http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/#looking-under-the-hood

[2] You could also write `datepickerInstance = $("#myElement").data("uiDatepicker");` where "uiDatepicker" is the widget's fullname in camel case ("ui" is the namespace of jQuery-UI internal widgets).