# Converting stringified JQuery object back to references?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I stringify a JQuery collection, it produces what appears to be a reference ID:

`JSON.stringify($('.btn'));`

`> '{"0":{"jQuery360064998935415166481":{"events":{"click":[...`

Obviously calling parse on this string will not produce a true JQuery object reference.  I'm curious if you can use this string identifier to obtain a reference to the original object, assuming the original object as still allocated?  What do these jQuery360064998935415166481 style identifiers represent?

I'm working with WASM where passing object references has limitations and requires unique approaches to fake preserve/restore handles to objects, and am wondering if these identifiers would be useful in my toolkit of approaches of overcoming these limitations.  I'd appreciate it greatly if we can avoid devolving into a discussion about the premise of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- No. You cannot convert back (parse) a stringified string to its original instance.
- That string is just the jQuery version with a random number attached. You can find a clue in the [jQuery's `core.js` file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/core.js#L190)

  ```
  jQuery.extend( {

      // Unique for each copy of jQuery on the page
      expando: "jQuery" + ( version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" ),
  ```

Basically:

```js
console.log(`jQuery${ ("3.6.0" + Math.random()).replace(/\D/g, "") }`);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.  Although it is randomly generated, it looks like it is leveraged as a unique ID for cache lookups, and was straightforward in older versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201455/84206

It's not as straightforward since it seems like the cache has been distributed among nodes so the lookup is alot more complex: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/699bcd396fa342c546905805a0cdfedd1959b7ce/src/selector.js#L539

Comment: Pretty janky at this point, but because `$(".btn")[0].jQuery360064998935415166481 !== undefined` I can do something like `$('*').filter(function(){return this["jQuery360064998935415166481"] !== undefined;}).length;` to find all the elements with this property.  It seems like this isn't a jQuery object ref though but instead the properties for holding data.  I see where they take `.expando` and append additional numbers to uniquify it further for storing attached data. In this case events and event handle information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not marking this as answer because I don't know that it's completely reliable or why it over-fetches in some cases.  It at least shows that it is possible to take the string expando ID and locate the object, and could probably be refined into something reliable:

https://jsfiddle.net/3hwvor46/

```
$('#btn1').on("click", function(e){
  console.log("clicked");
  var eventTargetExpandoId = Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.target)))[0];
  console.log(eventTargetExpandoId);
  // assume some context switch where we no longer have the e reference 
  // but only have the string eventTargetExpandoId and want to get the object ref back
  var foundWithProperty = $('*').filter(function(){return this[eventTargetExpandoId] !== undefined;});
  console.log("Count Items found", foundWithProperty.length);
  console.log("Items", foundWithProperty);
});
```

[image: Console showing located button]