# I know it's a reference cycle. But is it a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, cycle

The setup:

```
obj = object
obj.fun = function
obj.fun.ob = reference to obj
```

Does the garbage collector look for this type of cycle, or is this a leak?

Comment: If nothing else is referring to `obj` or `fun` then no

Comment: @elclanrs: e.g. circular linked list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular references in Javascript / Garbage collector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347203/circular-references-in-javascript-garbage-collector)

Comment: elclanrs, I am using this in Node.JS. It is the clearest way i could think of to allow my "class" functions to call their parent function in an override. the function calls the "Parent()" function. Parent() then gets the callee from the arguments and looks for the parent-reference member. It then scans the parent-class for a function with the same name. If found, it will call that function. That function, in turn might be an override as well; in that case, the cycle starts over using the parents' function this time.

Answer (score 2):

A modern, good garbage collector should be able to detect circular references like those. Rather, their ability to garbage collect is not hindered by such references (whether or not they actively look for such cases is a different story).

An example of a naive garbage collector affected by this problem is one that simply counts references and garbage collects only when the reference count goes to zero. However for the reason you pointed out above, this is not how garbage collectors are normally implemented.

There are many better garbage collection algorithms out there and a big subject in itself.

Comment: reference counting - it is not garbage collection

Answer (score 2):

Most JavaScript garbage collectors are mark and sweep garbage collectors, which do fine with this kind of thing. However:

In IE6 and previous, it could be a memory leak if `obj` is a COM object and `obj.fun` is a JavaScript function. IE6 and previous used the COM garbage collector (which is a reference counter) for COM objects and the JavaScript garbage collector (which is a mark and sweep collector) for JavaScript objects.

In IE7, it was still a memory leak, but it would be collected when the page was unloaded. But it could still leak while the page was up.

Comment: V8 is one of the most sophisticated JavaScript VMs out there. Don't worry, it can handle this with ease. :)

Answer (score 1):

The circular reference itself does not cause a memory leak. It depends a bit on what you consider a memory leak to include. At the moment, if nothing else refers to either of these objects, then they will be available for GC. However, if something else has a strong reference to one, both will be kept alive.

The usual cause of a memory leak is where you then set

```
    obj.fun = null;
```

And expect that will cause fun to be collected, forgetting that fun has a reference to obj. This is exactly what happens when you forget to unhook an event.