# JavaScript memory leaks with array.pop() or array.shift()

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-leaks

What does happen in memory when methods like `pop()` or `shift()` in JavaScript are being called in arrays which hold references to objects? Are memory spaces automatically marked for garbage collection?

Comment: Yes, if there are no other references to the objects, then that's what garbage collection does. What sort of memory leaks are you experiencing?

Comment: I didn't even know Javascript could leak memory.

Comment: Not experiencing yet. I just started developing in javascript and I wanted to know what happens when we pop a position in an array of references. Thanks guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular references in Javascript / Garbage collector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347203/circular-references-in-javascript-garbage-collector)