# Issue Using JavaScript's onmouseover Event Within a Class

Tags: javascript

Earlier today I got some simple code to work allowing an image to slide over on mouse over, and decided to try to turn that into a class so I could instantiate it. However, I'm running into some problems.

init() is called on window load, which sets up shifttabout() as a function to be called upon mousing over the image. However, when shifttabout() is called, I get the following error: "this.movetabout is not a function." How can this be?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function SlidingTab(img)
        {
            this.self = this;

            this.outtimer;
            this.intimer;

            this.left = 0;
            this.interval = 20;
            this.animatingout = false;
            this.animatingin = false;
            this.increment = 10;
            this.extenddist = 100;
            this.imgobj = img;


            this.movetabout = function(){
                alert("moveout");
                this.animatingout = true;
                this.left = parseInt(this.imgobj.style.left);

                if(this.left != this.extenddist)
                {
                    this.imgobj.style.left = this.left + this.increment + 'px';

                    this.self = this;
                    this.outtimer = setTimeout(this.self.movetabout, this.interval);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.animatingout = false;
                }
            };

            this.shifttabout = function(){
                alert("shiftout");
                if(this.animatingin)
                {
                    this.animatingin = false;
                    clearTimeout(this.intimer);
                }
                if(!this.animatingout)
                {
                    this.movetabout();
                }   
            }

            this.init = function(){
                this.imgobj.style.position = 'relative';
                this.imgobj.style.left = '0px';

                this.self = this;

                this.imgobj.onmouseover=this.self.shifttabout;
            }
        }

        function init(){
            var img1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
            var tab1 = new SlidingTab(img1);
            tab1.init();
        }

        window.onload = init;

    </script>
```

Presumably I am setting up the onmouseover function incorrectly somehow, since all class variables appear to be undefined or otherwise messed up in shifttabout() when it is called by mouse hover, but *not* when it is called directly via init().

Comment: One question, why are you using `this.self = this;`? Just as a side note, this creates a circular reference to the object, which can now never be garbage collected (probably not a huge perf issue, but it creates an arbitrary memory leak). Also, just paradigmatically, it's strange that you would create a property of the object that refers directly to itself...

Comment: @JoshBeam If circular references prevent the GC from cleaning it, it's a bug in the GC.

Comment: @Barmar, thus is the nature of JavaScript garbage collection. Knowing that, there's no need to create unnecessary circular references. Either way, I see no conceivable reason why you would ever need to do `this.self = this`. A strange pattern regardless of whether or not JS's GC isn't optimal.

Comment: @JoshBeam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347203/circular-references-in-javascript-garbage-collector

Comment: @Barmar, right, good post, thanks. I think my main point is more about this part of my original post: "Also, just paradigmatically, it's strange that you would create a property of the object that refers directly to itself."

Comment: Yeah, he might be confusing it with the need to create a closure variable `var self = this`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this

Comment: @Barmar, agreed (or, as the current top answer points out, using `Function.prototype.bind`).

Comment: @Barmar I was indeed confusing it with creating a closure variable. Just a remnant of my attempts to get my code to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem looks to be caused by these lines. Youre on the right track, in that you need to be properly setting the context of your function.

```
this.self = this;

this.imgobj.onmouseover=this.self.shifttabout;
```

change it to the following should properly set the context

```
this.imgobj.onmouseover=this.shifttabout.bind(this);
```

`#bind(this)` sets the scope of `this` inside the function to the input you pass it (in this case its the current scope)

Comment: Thanks -- this really helped! I also had to add a call to #bind(this) when setting the timeout in order for my code to work 100%, but this helped lead me there. Cheers ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The `this` you're using in the `shifttabout` refers to the `shifttabout` `this` - not the `SlidingTab` `this`.

You should pass the vars needed from outside `shifttabout` into it to use them properly.

Hope that helps.