# Javascript garbage collection: does this get deleted?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

JavaScript uses garbage collection, so objects, that don't get referred to anymore, get killed.

If I do `var a = {};` and then I do `a = null;`, the object gets deleted, because the only reference (a) doesn't refer to it anymore.

Now what if we have 2 objects referring to each other, but no one else referring to them, do those get deleted?

example:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};

a.ref = b;
b.ref = a;

a = null;
b = null;
```

The 2 objects are technically dead, but they refer to each other. Will they get deleted by the garbage collector or is this code example a memory leak ?

Comment: look here [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347203/circular-references-in-javascript-garbage-collector)

Comment: Thanks, that answers it.