# Adding variables to DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to ask, if is 'legal' to add custom variables to document body elements.
For example:

```
document.getElementById('elem1').customVariable = 'xxx';
```

This code just work, but i don't know if it is 'allowed'

It doesn't appear in list of tag's arguments, but variable is usable in further code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I add arbitrary properties to DOM objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258466/can-i-add-arbitrary-properties-to-dom-objects)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895560/javascript-dom-setting-custom-dom-element-properties is a better Q&A

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that will work, but the more common way to add custom attribute is like this:

```
<div id="elem1" data-customVariable="foo"
```

And then

```
document.getElementById('elem1').setAttribute("data-customVariable", "bar");
```

Or if older browser choke on `setAttribute`

```
document.getElementById('elem1')["data-customVariable"] ="bar";
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to pimvdb for pointing out that you can also do

```
document.getElementById('elem1').dataset.customVariable ="bar";
```

Just note that you'll have to watch how you name this -- the camel casing can throw it off.  You'll want

```
<div id="elem1" data-custom-variable="xxx"></div>
```

Comment: `elem.dataset.customVariable` is also possible with `data-` attributes - might be a bit cleaner.