# basic Javascript and html object execution

Tags: javascript, html, object

here is a basic program, I don't understand why this is not working:

a object class, houseObject.js:

```
var string;

    function createSentence(paragraph){
        this.string = paragraph;
    }

    function getString(){

        return string;  
    }
```

The program for running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="houseObject.js"></script>
<script>

   var temp = new createSentence("hello world");
   var string = temp.getString();
    var para=document.createElement("p");
    var node=document.createTextNode(string);
    para.appendChild(node);


</script>

</head>


<body>

<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script>
    var element=document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My second question is: why cant I put

```
    var element=document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
```

inside the head section of the html. Is it because html is a script program, it hasn't read the body section yet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a faster load and better performance you could put all the JS just before the end body tag.

Comment: Ah I got your problem. When you put the script into `head`, the element `div1` doesn't exist (yet). Place your scripts in the end of your HTML, or [use window.load or document.DOMContentLoaded events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: @metadings, oh I did though, I made another script section right before the end of body section

Comment: you would feel much more comfortable when using [`jQuery(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) - using jQuery also eliminates headaches about attachEvent/addEventListener, selecting elements by id, classes and other quirks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a constructor function to get an object back:

```
var Sentence = function (text) {
    this.text = text;
};
```

Now if you do

```
var obj = new Sentence("Hello World");
```

You have an `obj instanceof Sentence` and you can access the property like

```
console.log(obj.text); // prints Hello World
```

To "attach" this to a DOM element is a huge other answer. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895560/javascript-dom-setting-custom-dom-element-properties) why it's dangerous to reference the object directly on a DOMElement. Maybe you should start with [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) or you make an array or another object for storing id/object tuples:

```
var list = [ obj0, obj1 ];

var keyValueStore = { "key0": obj0, "key1" : obj1 };
```

Further extending the constructor function and it's object instances:

```
var Sentence = function (text) {
    this.para = document.createElement("p");
    this.setText(text);
};

Sentence.prototype.setText = function (text) {
    if (this.node) {
        this.para.removeChild(this.node);
    }
    this.node = document.createTextNode(text);
    this.para.appendChild(this.node);
};

Sentence.prototype.getText = function () {
    if (this.node) {
        if (!this.node.textContent) {
            // typical IE hack
            return this.node.innerText;
        }
        return this.node.textContent;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var sentence0 = new Sentence("Hello World");

    document.body.appendChild(sentence0.para);

    setTimeout(function () {
        sentence0.setText("I'm Edward!");
    }, 5000);

};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tfets/ (jsFiddle does auto-wrap a window.load handler).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you haven't quite grasped how objects work in Javascript works. `this.name` is not the same as  `name` which you appear to define globally. Read more about objects in Javascript at "[Introduction To Object Oriented Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. HTML documents are read sequentially, and JS code is executed when found. A script inside `<head>` cannot access nodes inside `<body>`, because they haven't been read yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you are working with Objects use Prototype, like this:

```
function createSentence(paragraph){
    this.paragraph = paragraph;
}

createSentence.prototype.getString = function(){
    alert(this.paragraph);
    //Or return this.paragraph
}

var string_1 = new createSentence('my sentence');
var string_2 = new createSentence('another sentence');

string_1.getString();
//Will return 'my sentence'

string_2.getString();
//Will return 'another sentence'
```